# Horizontal scroll bar visible when hovering on the faq tag in MSE and per-site meta

Tags: bug, design, per-site-meta, horizontal-scroll-bar

In the [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and per-site meta (communities which you were already joined) main page, the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag is in the right hand side bottom of the screen.

When hovering on the tag, there is a horizontal scroll bar is visible, but I can't use the scroll bar, it will disappear once your cursor navigate out of the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

Hope the horizontal scroll bar is not required. The scroll bar design issue in the Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox on Windows 10.

> [image: Horizontal_Scroll_Bar]

In the recent tag UI change also, the horizontal scroll bar is visible.

> [image: Horizontal_Scroll_Bar]

Comment: You can scroll horizontally using keyboard's arrows.